# Parsing and echoing JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, echo

Ok I have banged my head for the last 24hrs and cannot figure this out after testing and reading SO. I have a JSON file that I need to parse and for some reason I cannot get the right combination of code to echo anything out other than "Array" or "Trying to get property of non-object" or "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". Here is the full JSON that I am trying to iterate over. I need to print out the name of each 'project', the 'dataset' in each project, and the 'permissions' for each 'dataset'. I am building this JSON myself, so I can change the format if necessary.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Outputs JSON below:

```
[
   [
      {
         "projects":[
            {
               "project":"test-project-1",
               "datasets":[
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing1",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing1@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing2",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"OWNER",
                           "google_group":"testing2@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing3",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing3@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing4",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"WRITER",
                           "google_group":"testing4@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "project":"test-project-2",
               "datasets":[
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing1",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing1@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing2",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing2@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing3",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing3@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "dataset":"testing4",
                     "permissions":[
                        {
                           "role":"READER",
                           "google_group":"testing4@test.com"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
]
```

I have tried things like:

```
foreach($data->projects as $output)
{
    echo $output->project . "\n";
    foreach($output->datasets as $datasets)
    {
        echo $output->dataset . "\n";
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help!

EDIT: Working code that parses the JSON above:

```
$projects = $json['projects'];
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    echo $project['project'] . "<br>";
    foreach ($json['projects'][0]['datasets'] as $datasets){
        echo $datasets['dataset'] . "<br>";
        foreach ($json['projects'][0]['datasets'][0]['permissions'] as $permissions){
            echo $permissions['role'] . "<br>";
            echo $permissions['google_group'] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($output->dataset);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json contains two nested arrays, which contain the object, you want. So first you could use something like `[0][0]` to get the associative array, which contains the project.

```
// ...
$projects = $json['projects'];
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    echo "Project: " . $project['project'] . "\n";
    foreach ($project['datasets'] as $dataset) {
        echo "Dataset: " . $dataset['dataset'];
        foreach ($dataset['permissions'][0] as $key => $value) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Philip I'm getting somewhere, `$projects = $json[0][0]['projects'];` did not work but `$projects = $json['projects'];
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    echo $project['project'];
}`did work and successfully printed the 2 project names. How would I then proceed to print the dataset names and their permissions?

Comment: @user3282173 seems like, you posted the wrong json in your post, if you dont need the `[0][0]` part. However - I updated my answer to read permissions and datasets

Comment: Thanks Philip, you led me in the correct direction. I posted the updated code that now works and prints as expected. Thank you for the quick response!